# typescript-eslint rule to suggest collections that could be readonly?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

In Typescript, it's common to see functions like

```
function foo(list: string[]) {
  return list.map(...);
}
```

Note that the argument is not mutated.  The problem is that if I happen to have a `ReadonlyArray<string>` and try to pass it to the function, I get a type error.  (The same thing happens with `Set` and `Map`.)  Rather than discovering this somewhere down the line when I happen to try passing a `ReadonlyArray`, then going back and fixing it to accept the `Readonly` version, I'd like the linter to proactively catch the fact that I'm not calling a write-method anywhere in scope, and flag the parameter declaration.

I already found [this rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/prefer-readonly-parameter-types.md) but [apparently it's not intended for this use case](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/3897) -- it won't let you pass *any* mutable argument, including objects, class instances, etc.  I just want to flag mutable arguments in the case where they're never actually mutated.  Am I correct that this would be a good pattern to encourage?  Is there a plugin to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two popular ESLint plugins that can help enforce functional and/or immutable practices:

- https://github.com/eslint-functional/eslint-plugin-functional
- https://github.com/jhusain/eslint-plugin-immutable

Specifically, [`functional/prefer-immutable-types`](https://github.com/eslint-functional/eslint-plugin-functional/blob/e4bd4ad79502ff77ae26e703e1761ab80a46868b/docs/rules/prefer-immutable-types.md) enforces types being declared as readonly.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to have to read the docs but I think the "shallow" options might be what I'm looking for.